# Can I use the asymptotic expansion of the Error function for complex arguments?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, asymptotics, error-function

I tried to evaluate a limit of the form
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{erfi}\left(zx\right) $$
for some complex number $z\neq0$. Following [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2811632) one idea would be to write $iz=\left|z\right|e^{i\mathrm{arg}(iz)}$ and then use the asmyptotic expansion of the error function at $\infty$. Is this a possible way of calculating these limits? Can I just plug in complex values into the asymptotic expansion? I don't know much about these expansions, for example how they are obtained.

Comment: Just for reference: https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfi/06/02/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It is technically true that you cannot do this with arbitrary functions. HOWEVER, the error function is a "homomorphic" function, which when dealing with complex functions means that it is continuous and complex differentiable across the complex plane wherever it is finitely defined. When dealing with complex functions, a function is holomorphic if and only if it is also "analytic", meaning its Taylor Series expansions converge to the function when they converge. The error function is indeed analytic, [as cited here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540112000697).